# Angular is reloading components on navigation

Tags: angular

The following intermittent bug is occurring in my angular project: Sometimes when the user clicks on a menu item that contains the "routerLink" directive, all angular components are reloaded, but there are times when this behavior doesn't happen (which would be correct).

The intermittent problem also recurs if I directly use the "navigate" function of "@angular/router" in a ".ts" file (eg: router.navigate(['/login'])).

Does anyone know a possible reason for the problem?

Comment: Please add your routing module and also how you are calling the router link too

Comment: Can you share your code so we could try to reproduce the bug if possible?

Answer (score 0):

For navigating to another page use router Link as  routerLink="/signup"
Refer the below code

```html
<div>
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
<li class="nav-item">
<a routerLink="/cart" class="nav-link active" >Cart</a>
</li>
<li  class="nav-item">
<a routerLink="/login"  class="nav-link active" >Login</a>
</li>
<li  class="nav-item">
<a routerLink="/signup" class="nav-link active">Signup</a>
</li>
</ul>
 </div>
```